# How to manage immutable class with LinkedList as an instance field?

Tags: java, class, field, immutability

I have an immutable class called `Employees` like this:

```
public final class Employees {
    private final List<Person> persons;

    public Employees() {
        persons = new LinkedList<Person>();
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }
}
```

How do I keep this class immutable?

I made the field `private` and `final`, and I didn't provide a setter method. Is this enough to achieve immutability?

Comment: "is it enough to achieve that?" - No, because I could still call `getPersons().add( somePerson )`.

Comment: No. Not by a long shot.

Comment: Very related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137224/immutable-object-with-arraylist-member-variable-why-can-this-variable-be-chang and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006040/immutability-of-a-class-when-an-instance-variable-present-as-arraylist and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984890/objects-in-an-immutable-class-as-member-variable

Comment: Is `Person` mutable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answer edited to explain not only the case with a mutable version of `Person`, but also with an immutable version of `Person`.

---

Your class is mutable because you can do that:

```
Employees employees = new Employees();
employees.getPersons().add(new Person());
```

Note that not passing a list of persons to the constructor if you change your code to create an immutable class you will have a not useful class holding an ever empty list of persons, so I assume that is necessary to pass a `List<Person>` to the constructor.

Now there are two scenarios, with different implementations:

- `Person` is immutable
- `Person` is mutable

---

**Scenario 1 - `Person` is immutable**

You need only to **create an immutable copy of the persons parameter in the constructor**.

You need also to **make `final` the class or at least the method `getPersons`** to be sure that nobody provide a mutable overwritten version of the `getPersons` method.

```
public final class Employees {
    private final List<Person> persons;

    public Employees(List<Person> persons) {
        persons =  Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(persons));
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }
}
```

---

**Scenario 2 - `Person` is mutable**

You need to **create a deep copy of `persons` in the `getPersons` method**.

You need to **create a deep copy of `persons` on the constructor**.

You need also to **make `final` the class or at least the method `getPersons`** to be sure that nobody provide a mutable overwritten version of the `getPersons` method.

```
public final class Employees {
    private final List<Person> persons;

    public Employees(List<Person> persons) {
        persons = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Person person : persons) {
            persons.add(deepCopy(person));   // If clone is provided 
                                           // and creates a deep copy of person
        }
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        List<Person> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Person person : persons) {
            temp.add(deepCopy(person)); // If clone is provided 
                                         // and creates a deep copy of person
        }  
        return temp;
    }

    public Person deepCopy(Person person) {
        Person copy = new Person();  
        // Provide a deep copy of person
        ...
        return copy;
    }
}
```

---

This part of the answer is to show why a not deep copy of the `personsParameter` passed to the constructor can create mutable versions of `Employees`:

```
List<Person> personsParameter = new ArrayList<>();
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Pippo");
personsParameter.add(person);
Employees employees = new Employees(personsParameter);

// Prints Pippo    
System.out.println(employees.getPersons().get(0).getName()); 


employees.getPersons().get(0).setName("newName");

// Prints again Pippo    
System.out.println(employees.getPersons().get(0).getName()); 

// But modifiyng something reachable from the parameter 
// used in the constructor 
person.setName("Pluto");

// Now it prints Pluto, so employees has changed    
System.out.println(employees.getPersons().get(0).getName());
```

Comment: Well, if you are allowed to change the original Object then yes, you are right, we will need defensive copies. What i am trying to say is if `Person` class ensures that it is immutable, then the container (`List`) doesn't have to worry about `Person'`s immutablility. All it has to worry about is ensuring that only the List is immutable. when nobody can change the state of an object, the same object can be passed around :)

Comment: @Davide Lorenzo MARINO - Thanks for your reply, it is very clear. I would like to add one thing, I checked Defensive Copies Item on Joshua Block's "Effective Java". he says this "clone method [...] could return an instance of an untrusted subclass specifically designed for malicious mischief. [...] Do not use the clone method to make a defensive copy of a parameter whose type is subclassable by untrusted parties ". So to ensure efficient copy, it's better not to use Clone, but copying all fields of Person manually, in your example.

Comment: You can use the clone of a custom class like Person  without problems because is you the author of the clone method.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO in which case, it is better to write a copy ctor or `static` copy method - `clone()` has **massive** issues; being the author of the method does not solve this as you still need to call `super.clone()` and those issues are still present. I was tempted to downvote this answer just for the use of `clone()` in fact; but decided against. What this answer really misses is a simple explanation - "a `class` is immutable iff it and all of its members are immutable". So if `Person` were immutable, the whole `clone()` nonsense could be avoided.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, assuming that Person is an immutable class simplify a lot all. Not only the clone() (or equivalent) is not necessary, but also copy of the List persons is not necessary if you take care creating it as an immutable list. Basically in this case you need only to create the immutable List persons in the constructor.

Comment: You do not need a deep clone unless `Person` is mutable. Additionally, the OP "being the author of `Person`" does not make `clone` safe. That class must be *designed* such that clone is safe. In particular, this means that it must be implemented either using only primitive instance variables (unlikely to stay that way) or then deep clone all its own data. It would generally just be better to make `Person` immutable (or create an immutable variation) than worry about all that. -1

Comment: @jomc26 and to all - To be more precise I added both scenarios, with a mutable version of Person and with an immutable version of `Person`. Additionally, assuming also that `Person` is not under the control of the programmer I added the `deepCopy` method explicitly instead of propose the `clone`.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO In the case Person is Mutable, why in the get method you create a new copy of the instance field? Can't we return simply the copy created in the constructor?

Comment: @Szanownego if Person is mutable returning directly the persons inside the List you can modify the Person itself so you will change the Employees content. Basically you can do something like employees.getPersons().get(0).setName("New name"); this will change the content of employees.

Answer (score 17):

No, it is not enough because in java even *references are passed by value*. So, if your `List's` reference escapes ( which will happen, when they call `get`), then your class is no longer *immutable*.

You have 2 choices :

1. Create a defensive copy of your `List` and return it when get is called.
2. Wrap your List as an immutable / Unmodifiable `List` and return it (or replace your original `List` with this, then you can return this safely without further wrapping it)

Note : You will have to ensure that `Person` is either immutable or create defensive copies for each `Person` in the `List`

Comment: If person is mutable, and a list is passed to the constructor  as parameter you need to create also a defensive copy of it in the constructor. Making a defensive copy in the getter is not enough. Also wrapping in an immutable list is not enough if person is mutable.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO - What the OP has to ensure is that all transitively reachable objects are either immutable or take care of returning defensive copies

Comment: no as I said is not enough if a mutable parameter is passed to the constructor and no deep defensive copy of it is done on the constructor. I try to edit my answer to show that.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO - if I get a reference of a object which has no public fields and setters, how can I modify it?. Every composed Object ahs to ensure that it is immutable OR the parent containing a mutable object has to ensure that it returns defensive copies

Comment: @TheLostMind - Can you Explain me better the second solution, what does it mean "Wrap your List as an immutable / Unmodifiable List"?

Comment: @Szanownego - After the `List` is constructed. Use `persons = Collections.unmodifiableList(persons)`. And in your `getPersons` return `persons`

Answer (score 8):

The answer is found in the docs - [A Strategy for Defining Immutable Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html):

1. Don't provide "setter" methods — methods that modify fields or objects referred to by fields.
2. Make all fields final and private.
3. Don't allow subclasses to override methods.
4. **If the instance fields include references to mutable objects, don't allow those objects to be changed**:

   4.1. Don't provide methods that modify the mutable objects.

   4.2. Don't share references to the mutable objects. Never store references to external, mutable objects passed to the constructor; if necessary, create copies, and store references to the copies. Similarly, create copies of your internal mutable objects when necessary to avoid returning the originals in your methods.

Answer (score 6):

You could do even better with

```
import java.util.Collections;
...
public List<Person> getPersons() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList( persons);
}
```

Comment: This is mutable because you can mutate a single person. myInstance.getPersons().get(0).setName("pippo");

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO -But that cannot be prevented from here. Don't provide setters in `Person` then.

Comment: @TheLostMind is not enough don't provide setters on Person. If Person is not unodifiable you can have always a possibility to change Employees

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO - Well yes, either the OP can created defensive copies of all elements of the List or ensure that an existing Person cannot be modified by using constructor injection and no setters.

Comment: @TheLostMind Is not enough. If you pass a mutable variable to the constructor and you don't make a deep copy of it in the constructor, also not exposing setters you can modify the original parameter passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

In this case I would favour not exposing the List or Map at all.  If you pass out the collection are you breaking encapsulation by assuming it must be stored as a List.

If you don't expose the List, you can avoid needing to wrap it or provide a defensive copy.

```
public final class Employees {
    private final List<Person> persons;

    public Employees() {
        persons = new LinkedList<Person>();
    }

    public Person getPerson(int n) {
        return persons.get(n);
    }  

    public int getPersonCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }
}
```

The reason you want to avoid defensive copies is they can be called a lot. Someone could easily write (you would be surprised how often this is written)

```
for (int i = 0; i < employees.getPersons().size(); i++) {
    Person p = employees.getPersons().get(i);

}
```

By giving specific methods you can optimise the code for that use case.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to require an `Employees` instance to be initialized with a set of `Person` ?

Comment: Actually, this is a good option. This way we only have to ensure that `Person` is either immutable / defensive copy is returned

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with that approach is that I still can do getPersons().add(x). For not allowing that, you have to create a constructor that receives the list of persons and then instantiate your internal final list as, for example, [ImmutableList](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html).
The rest of the code seems alright for me.

EDIT:

as Davide Lorenzo MARINO points, this is not enough. You also would need to return a deep copy of the list in the getter, so users can't modify your internal list by the getter returned reference.

By doing this you can just have a normal LinkedList as your itnernal List (private final). On your constructor you create a deep copy of the List and on your getter you return a deep copy of your internal List.

Comment: Is not enough. You need to be sure that all that can be reached from the list must be copied or immutable. Basically you need to make a deep copy both in the constructor and in the getter.